# Octave:warning: the 'optimoptions' function belongs to the optim package from Octave Forge but has not yet been implemented

Tags: matlab, octave

I run some function which require "optimoptions" function. I run pkg load optim. But when I use the function I get the error 
warning: the 'optimoptions' function belongs to the optim package from Octave
Forge but has not yet been implemented.

Please read https://www.octave.org/missing.html to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.

Comment: You can use `optimset`. Maybe related https://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimoptions-and-optimset.html

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding using optimset e.g. doesn't seem to work with linprog